# Processing two unassociated Rails models' forms in one controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mechanize, rails-activerecord

I'm creating a Rails app that will take in input from two models and their respective forms, and then log into a website with Mechanize and do hundreds of tasks there.

The first form consists of the user's login information (the username and password, using the model `User`), and the second one is a long list of term names and their respective definitions (using the model `Term` and uploaded into the form as an Excel doc).

I have no need to associate these two models (unlike in similar SO questions, which seem to deal with nested models). Once this Mechanize task completes, I will destroy both models' objects from the database.

The two pieces of the app (logging in to the website; and uploading the terms and using them to interact with the website) both work perfectly in separate scripts.

My question is: How can I take in both models' information on one webpage and coordinate the controller(s) accordingly? In this situation, can I create both objects in one controller? (If not, that's fine, as long as there's an alternative; I'm game for whatever will get this to work.)

I'm posting some of my code below. I'm happy to answer any questions you may have. Please keep in mind I am pretty new at Rails, so is not very elegant code:

The `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :username, :password
end
```

And the `Term` model:

```
class Term < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :definition
end
```

In my `terms` controller (the forms are located in the `index` action and the script is run in the `show` action):

```
def create
 @term = Term.new(params[:term])
 @user = User.new(params[:user])

  if (@term.save && @user.save)
    flash[:notice] = "Your terms have been sent for processing."
    redirect_to terms_path
  else
    render :action => 'index'
  end
end     

 def show
   @term = Term.all
   agent = Mechanize.new

   page = agent.get('www.myurl.com')
   #log into the website
   @user.username = myform.field_with(:id => "userfield").value
   @user.password = myform.field_with(:id => "passfield").value
   #and then enter the term information into the website's forms
   rest of Mechanize code goes here...
 end
```

And in `views/terms/index.html.erb`:

```
#the login form:
<%= render 'loginform' %> 

#the term file uploader:
<%= form_tag import_terms_path, multipart: true do %> 
<%= file_field_tag :file %>
<%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<% end %>

<br>
<table id="terms">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Definition</th>
  </tr>

#displays the uploaded terms on the index page
<% @terms.each do |term| %> 
  <tr>
    <td><%= term.name %></td>
    <td><%= term.definition %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<p><%= link_to 'Update website with these terms', terms_update_terms_path %></p>
```

And in `views/terms/_loginform.erb`:

```
 <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label_tag(:username, 'Username') %><br />
  <%= f.text_field_tag(:user, :username) %>
</div>
<div class="field">
 <%= f.label_tag(:password, 'Password') %><br />
 <%= f.password_field_tag(:user, :password) %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And in `views/terms/_termform.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(@term) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :name %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :definition %><br />
   <%= f.text_area :definition %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to save the data and truly don't want to associate the models, I would save the Term separately:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :username, 'Username' %>
      <%= f.text_field :username %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= label_tag :name %>
      <%= text_field_tag :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= label_tag :definition %>
      <%= text_field_tag :definition %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Then in your controller:

```
@term = Term.new

@term.attributes = {
:name => params[:name],
:definition => params[:definition]
}

@term.save
```

If you are adding multiple term fields to the form, I would consider something like [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), and just add an each loop for saving the Terms in the controller.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I'm a bit confused, and that may very well be due to me being new to Rails. In your form for `@user`, the attributes for `@term` are also in there - why is that? And also: can you please clarify how your controller code should be implemented in my current setup? (ie, in which action, and what other code should be removed to make place for it?) And does this mean that I do not need a `users` controller?

Comment: Hi CodeBiker, the controller code would go in your users#create action. In my form code, the attributes for Term are simply passed as parameters (rather than in a :term hash) which eliminates the need for a nested form per your description.